# Build a half screen window kit that can slide up and down

Tags: windows, screens

All the "build a screen" kits I can find are only for fixed screens and do not have hardware that allows easy manipulation to slide the screen up and down a track. While they can stay in place above the sill by the tension of the spring clips, there's nothing to grab onto to change the positioning! I'm looking for a kit that either has a lip at the bottom for fingers to grab onto, or have finger latch springs like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ooq6cG-fikE

[image: screen window with lip]

Comment: glue a short section of trim or aluminum angle to the bottom. You can simply snap a binder clip around it, but it look janky.

Comment: "looking for a kit" is shopping advice and, therefore, Off Topic. A simple, but not shopping recommendation might be to run two screws through the bottom of the aluminum frame and use them as handles. You run the risk, of course, of destroying the frame as you do that. I must say, though, that the horizontal fold of metal in your picture looks to me _very much_ like a little finger hold that you can grab on to in order to slide the screen up and down. Does that not work?

Comment: @FreeMan I don't think my question implied I was looking for shopping advice or comparing deals or for someone to shop for me. I want to know if a product like this even exists for purchase, because it clearly exists in my pre-existing screen windows (as seen in my picture). I don't want to replace my entire double hung window just to get a replacement screen.